# Why does Kane wear a mask one week, and the next not?

Tags: history, pro-wrestling, wwe

Why does Kane wear a mask one week, and the next week he is without a mask?

Comment: Because of what the "E" in WWE stands for.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about WWE Storylines. Questions about WWE Storylines can be asked at [Movies & TV SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/). [Meta Reference](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/558)

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the storyline. This is known in pro-wrestling as [kayfabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayfabe).

From the beginning of the character's career until around 2003, Kane was masked. He was unmasked for a long period of time (long after I stopped following pro-wrestling) after that.

Last year, he had been unmasked to carry out his role as the "Director of Operations"<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kane_%28wrestler%29#Director_of_Operations_.282013.E2.80.93present.29)</sub> as part of "The Authority." After WrestleMania XXX, Stephanie McMahon and Kane had a [vignette](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2050163-bryan-vs-kane-examining-stephanie-mcmahons-potential-role-in-title-match) that ultimately led to a remasking and thereafter referring him to as 
"The Demon Kane."